# Using webshot and robervable

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, htmlwidgets

I would like to include screenshots from an observable notebook in an rmarkdown rendered to pdf. Directly including code blocks that call `robservable` does not work, so I thought I could use the `webshot` package instead. The example below creates a file, `test.html`, that does contain the interactive notebook. However, the rendered pdf still does not show any screenshot.

````
    ---
    title: "robservable and webshot"
    output: pdf_document
    ---

   ```{r}
   knitr::opts_chunk$set(screenshot.opts = list(delay = 5))
   library("robservable")
   library("webshot")
   library("htmlwidgets")
   library("dplyr")
   ```

   This is a test.

   ```{r}
   f <- "test.html"
   robservable("@d3/horizontal-bar-chart", include = "chart") %>%
     saveWidget(f)
   ```

   ```{r}
   webshot(f)
   ```
````

[image]